# How to export Stata xtcsd test results?

Tags: stata, panel-data

I would like to export results of cross section dependence tests for 12 panel data sets to a table in order to compare them with similar tests done with different software. Below is the regression and test instruction example from the `xtcsd` help page (unfortunately the example dataset is not available but a similar example dataset  [tbl15-1.dta](https://ideas.repec.org/p/boc/bocins/tbl15-1.html) from the `xttest2` page is available). The instruction below will help you understand what I'm trying to achieve:

```
use "http://fmwww.bc.edu/ec-p/data/Greene2000/TBL15-1.dta"
xtset firm year
xtreg i f c,fe
xtcsd, pesaran
```

To display the test statistic, I can use

```
return list
```

How do I acess the p-value for that statistic?

I have found how to export **estimation results** using the command `esttab`. 
How do I export **test results** to a file in Stata?

Following @Maarten Buis's comment below on the p-value, here is how I exported test results to a csv file using the low level file access:

```
file open xtcsdfile using xtcsd.csv, write replace
file write xtcsdfile "pesaran,pvalue" _n
file write xtcsdfile (r(pesaran)) "," (2*(normal(-abs(r(pesaran))))) _n
file close xtcsdfile
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about exporting test results to a file.

Comment: `esttab` is a command, not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pesaran statistic will (asymptotically) follow a standard normal distribution if the null-hypothesis is true, so: the p-value is `2*(normal(-abs(r(pesaran))))`

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out by looking at `viewsource xtcsd.ado` (it used `norm()` from STATA version 6 which has been renamed to `normal()`). My STATA command to extract the Pesaran test p-value becomes `display 2*(1-normal(abs(r(pesaran))))`

Comment: I would use `normal(-something)` instead of `1-normal(something)` as the former is more numerically stable than the latter. For more see: http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0025